# Meteor Parse json results into span or div?

Tags: javascript, css, json, meteor

I am trying to make a page using meteor that displays the latest powerball results.

So far I have a working page using:

RESULTS.JS

```
Template.results.helpers({
  results: function () {
    return Session.get('lottery-results');
  },
  winning: function() {
    return Session.get('winning')
  }
});

Template.results.rendered = function(){
  Session.set('lottery-results', []);
  HTTP.get("http://data.ny.gov/resource/d6yy-54nr.json", function (err, result) {
    Session.set('lottery-results', JSON.parse(result.content) );
  });
};

Template.results.events({
  'change #date': function (e, tmpl) {
    Session.set('winning', $('#date option:selected').data('winning'))
  }
});

Template.results.destroyed = function(){
Session.set('winning', []);
};
```

and

RESULTS.HTML

```
<template name="results">
<select id="date">
<option>Select a date</option>
{{#each results}}
<option data-winning="{{ winning_numbers }}">{{dateFormat draw_date  format="MM/DD/YYYY"}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
<h1>{{ winning }}</h1>
</template>
```

I want to style the results so that the numbers come out inside of a ball.  The first 5 numbers would be one style (white balls)and the last number< the powerball, would be it's own style (red ball).  I think I need to somehow parse the results into spans or divs but I don't know how. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this you can check out the code at
 http://meteorpad.com/pad/yDbDX3WebMA5wuLKr/Leaderboard